Use Google reCAPTCHA v3 to conditionally load Dynamics Real-time Marketing Form in WordPress?
I have a Real-time marketing form from Dynamics 365 that I have embedded on my WordPress website via JavaScript in a raw code block via Elementor pagebuilder. I want to add a reCAPTCHA check, but I do not want to implement Dynamic form's default captcha or their method for integrating Google reCAPTCHA. Instead, I want to know if it is feasible to only load the form when users pass the reCAPTCHA check.
Is this doable? And how would one go about achieving this?
Please let me know, any help or insight is appreciated, thank you!
I have checked the reCAPTCHA v3 documentation where it explains you can programmatically invoke the challenge which I understand. However, I do not understand how I can conditionally prevent the embedded form from loading. If someone can provide their insight on this that'd be great!
